# How to globally define the aesthetics of a color bar guide in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, legend, colorbar

I have a plot that has a legend with a color bar. By default tick marks are white. I can change them to black in each plot using `guides(fill = guide_colorbar(ticks.colour = "black")`. Is there any way to make this modification in a generalized way? Maybe inside `theme_set()` or `theme()`

```
library(ggplot2)

X <- 1:3
Y <- 1:3

DF <- expand.grid(X = X,
                  Y = Y)

DF$Z <- 1:9

p <-  ggplot(data = DF,
             aes(x = X,
                 y = Y,
                 fill = Z)) +
  geom_tile()

p + guides(fill = guide_colorbar(ticks.colour = "black",
                                 frame.colour = "black"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the ticks color cannot be changed globally but the frame around the legend can with `theme_set`. Create a custom theme and then set it as the default one.

```
theme_Daniel <- function(){ 
  theme_minimal() %+replace%    #replace elements we want to change
    theme(
      legend.box.background = element_rect(color = "black")
    )
}

theme_set(theme_Daniel())
p
```